# Google chrome Upload Speed vs Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Application is uploading a large file. Google Chrome is reaching maximum of 800 to 900Mbps on LocalHost. But Firefox can reach up to 2Gbps or more! Why this much difference? Changing responseType to blob helped in GET request. How to make upload (POST request) faster on Google Chrome.

```
 function sendRequest(n){
    var Self = this;
        Self.newTime = Date.now();
        Self.Open = new XMLHttpRequest();

      Self.Open.upload.onprogress = function(event){
        console.log("Upload Pregress")

        Self.CurTime = (Date.now() - Self.newTime);
        Self.OverallCurTime = (Date.now() - Self.OverallTime) / 1000;
        Self.EventData = event.loaded;
        Self.EventTotal = event.total;
        Self.SpeedData = (parseFloat((8000 * (Self.EventData /Self.CurTime[n]) / 1048576)));
        }

       Self.Open.open("POST", "upload.bin" + "?n=" +  Math.random(), true);
       Self.Open.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "arrayBuffer");
       Self.Open.responseType = "blob";
       Self.Open.send(Self.UploadData);

    }
```

Comment: can you please tell me what's the purpose of doing this ? what you are trying to accomplish i mean!

Comment: and speaking of the request type, you should consider that GET requests tend to perform better than POST requests

Comment: is your chrome 32bit and your Firefox 64 bit?

Comment: @dandavis Firefox and chrome both are 32 bit. I am answering this because I am facing a similar issue

Answer (score 5):

If we could exclude the difference from the JS engine speed" Chrome VS Firefox, then in theory your test case should not happen.

I would advise you to take a look at the following open bugs from chrome regarding the blob

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=blob&colspec=ID+Pri+M+Stars+ReleaseBlock+Component+Status+Owner+Summary+OS+Modified&x=m&y=releaseblock&cells=ids

But just to make focus on the possibility of the bug being the answer for your question, I can also show you other bugs using Blob in Firefox:

*"**XMLHttpRequest of large data (approx 140MB) with response type "blob" returns a corrupt file (about 600,000 bytes around 9M in the blob appear incorrect).**"*

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1349862

Also, if I make a count on bugs related to the word "blob", then Firefox only has 177 bugs found VS 751 in Chrome.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=Blob